# Serve linked css and js with Go net/http

Tags: go

I cannot make net/http serve html file with the linked css and script file.

I have

```
site/lib/ratchet/css/ratchet.css
site/lib/ratchet/js/ratchet.js
```

in my project folder structure, and

```
site/src/index.html
```

and in this index.html I have included two files

```
<link href="../lib/ratchet/css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="../lib/ratchet/js/ratchet.js"></script>
```

and Go function to serve it is:

```
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "/Users/faruk/dev/otp/site/src/index.html")
}
```

in main():

```
r.HandleFunc("/", index).
    Methods("GET")
```

I make use of gorilla/mux above.

I can view it from the browser but with only html. the two linked file has been given 404.

Can not `http.ServeFile` intended for this purpose to automatically resolve the linked css and js files to serve the index.html or alike files?
What is the standard way to serve an html file in Go net/http?

Comment: you mean in the linked files to static html file case we need this always in Go?

Comment: Really do yourself a favour, and use a proper webserver like [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) for static file serving.

Comment: I am development phase. Isn't there a proper and non-cumbersome way to achieve this? A web server should already be able to resolve the linked files in html.

Comment: @fsc: that's not how http/html works. The webserver only returns what the browser requets.

Comment: yes, it can be done, you can be right. But I do not understand why -4.

Comment: An http server that can resolve its static html files' linked assets is not unusual. And if go net/http require extra one line, it is the answer of jmaloney, and is welcome, and is not cumbersome as opposed to returning comments with down votes from someone, if not all, who know about it but do not know it by the exact words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a file server to serve the files found in your lib directory.  Go has a file server in the http package

```
func init() {
    http.Handle("/lib/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/Users/faruk/dev/otp/site/")))
}
```

Comment: thanks it works now. but I had to change the name init(). compiler complains about undefined init. may be a reserved name issue we hit here. Another name works seamlessly.

Comment: You can't call `init()`. Anything defined in `func init()` will get run automaticly before `func main()`.